# Trying to make MAMP local server site accessible externally, via airport base station

Tags: home-networking, port-forwarding, home-server, airport, mamp

I am bumbling around in network and airport settings.

- I've set up port forwarding on Netgear DGN2000 router but I'm not sure **how to configure the airport extreme** base station. It is in bridge mode, with auto IPv6.
- I think I have assigned a static IP address to the machine running the server, but have probably done this wrong.
- I've checked with Network Utility that the port 8888 is open.
- Yet I don't seem to be able to make the (Wordpress) site accessible externally (according to client).
- Also, is there a good way to check this myself from home, apart from using the browser on my phone on 3G?

Comment: First, don't do double NAT. Only the one box at the head of your network should be doing NAT. Everything else should be just a bridge. Also, for us to tell you how to set it up, you'll have to tell us your network topology and what ports on which boxes you mapped to which IP addresses and ports on which other boxes.

Comment: As a noob, I`m sure <i've messed this up by overenthusiastic, blind tinkering.  But I don't think I turned on NAT on any box.  I just set told the router and the airport extreme to allow port forwarding to port 8888 on the server machine's static IP address, with no dynDNS, and turned off as many firewalls as possible...

Comment: Port forwarding is a NAT thing. Most home gateway routers do it by default. You have to turn it off on the boxes that shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: OK, no NAT on the airport box but still no joy.

Comment: Okay, now say what port you opened externally on the Netgear, what IP address and port you mapped it to, what (hopefully static) IP address your server currently says it has, and what port it's listening on for this purpose.

Comment: I set the IP address of the server machine to ***.***.1.201. MAMP says it's listening to 8888, so I opened that port on the Netgear, and mapped it to the same port on the IP address of the server machine. Then I set the address of the Wordpress installation to the server IP address/8888.

Comment: And when you test this from your phone on 3G, you point your browser at http://your-netgears.public.ip.address:8888/ ?

Comment: No, I have been using the server machine's IP address.  Let's try this...

Comment: Is that the ADSL IP address or the LAN IP address?

Comment: The ADSL address, I think.  But that didn't work. Should the Airport IPv6 be set to link local, host or tunnel?

Comment: Aha!  Nearly!  i can access the server from my phone on 3G *but not the wordpress site!*  What have I missed?

Comment: OK, now mobile safari 3G has accessed the site VERY slowly but is not rendering it correctly ' it is not fully formatted and links don't seem to work...